# Increase memory limits for cordova build at visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, gradle, out-of-memory, visual-studio-cordova

I have a cordova project at which I enabled multidex because we reached the limit.
After this I started to receive the following error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

1. Could you tell how I can increase java heap size if I'm using Visual Studio for cordova application build?
2. Also could you tell how to increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle? I'd like to increase build speed.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Could you tell how I can increase java heap size if I'm using Visual Studio for cordova application build?

You can follow the steps of `Could not create Java Virtual Machine error` Section of [TACO Official Document](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tips-and-workarounds-android-readme/) to increase the jvm heap size.

> 2. Also could you tell how to increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle? I'd like to increase build speed.

To speed up build action, you can add following properties into the `Gradle.properties` file under `project folder\platform\android\`:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
```

In Corodva project, the changes under platforms folder will be overrided by every build. So it is best to write a `before_build` hook to copy the file into android platform:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Q;
module.exports = function (context) {
    Q = context.requireCordovaModule('q');
    var defered = Q.defer();
    var path = context.opts.projectRoot;
    try {
    fs.createReadStream(path + '\\myconfigs\\gradle.properties').pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path + '\\platforms\\gradle.properties'));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    console.log("afterBuild==>End");
    defered.resolve();
}
```

And I create the `Gradle.properties` under `Project Folder\myconfigs` folder:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I tried to setup _JAVA_OPTIONS variable to -Xmx2048M. After this I'm receiving the following error: "Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed".

Comment: Could you please try override the jdk environment path to your jdk folder. You can find the setting under `Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Environment Variable Overrides`,

Comment: Yes. It is overriden. I'm using the following path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

Comment: Could you please try using x64 jdk and set the system environment variables for JAVA_HOME and add it into path.

Comment: The same issue. As soon I set _JAVA_OPTIONS I start to receive error that JDK is not installed. If I remove it there is no such error.